# How to raycasting only one target Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hello guys ive been working on my project to create FSM for AI on FPS game, i have a problem about raycast, if there is only one target my code working so perfect but if there is two targets or more i have some problem, i just wanted to raycast only one target but  i dont know how to do it, here is my code for raycast using ontriggerstay

```
void OnTriggerStay (Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "CT")
    {
        collideWithPlayer = true;
        Vector3 direction = other.transform.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(direction, transform.forward);

        if(angle < fieldOfViewAngle * 0.5f )
        {
            RaycastHit hit;

            if((Physics.Raycast(transform.position , direction, out hit, col.radius)))
            {
                Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, hit.point - transform.position, Color.cyan);

                if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "CT")
                {
                        aliveTarget = hit.point;
                        playerInSight = true;
                        transform.LookAt(aliveTarget);
                }

                else if ((hit.collider.gameObject.tag != "CT") ) {playerInSight = false;  }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

ive tried so many ways but  still didnt work, im newbie anyways :D so maybe u guys can help me. the problem here is if one target already on sight (player insight should be true) and the other target come inside vision but covered by obstacle, player insight will triggered false.this is because this script will raycast anyone come inside that vision so i just want to raycast only one target and not raycasting again when theres a target on sight. maybe this is a newbie question for you guys, im sorry for asking a newbie question but im so stressed right now, please help me thankyou.

maybe the problem on the script is on if statement or ontriggerstay()?

Comment: When you check for raycast, check if there is any object found yet to stop raycast check.

Comment: thanks for your comment, and how to check if there is any object found yet ? ive tried with bool and it didnt work

Comment: Why do you raycast for "CT" object when you have collided with it? And do you mean having multiple "CT" objects makes problem or other objects as well?

Comment: im using raycast  for knowing if the target is behind obstacle or not. my problem is when the other target come inside the angle, its triggering playerInSight = false although there is a target on sight.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily change the layer of the target to a special one, for example, "hittest" and make sure no other gameobjects belong to this layer now, then make the raycast on that layer only. Remember to restore the layer of the target to the original one after the test was finished. I am posting from a mobile phone so I cannot write code at present but I can provide some sample code later if u need future assitant.

Comment: thanks for your comments, i would really appreciate if you can provide some sample code for me, especially how to mark the special one :D

Comment: heey dude, im still stuck right now, can i have your email for discussing my problems ? thanks

Comment: In OnTriggerStay(), when you found the a target, save it in a class variable, say currentTarget. The next time entering OnTriggerStay(), check if targetObject is still on sight, if it is, just continue to use it. If it is not, do RayCast to find another one.

Comment: can you provide me with a simple code ? how to save a target

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is your scenario, but this might work:

```
if(angle < fieldOfViewAngle * 0.5f )
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position , direction, out hit, col.radius))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, hit.point - transform.position, Color.cyan);

        if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "CT")
        {
            aliveTarget = hit.point;
            playerInSight = true;
            transform.LookAt(aliveTarget);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        playerInSight = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working, playerinsight will true even if the target behind the wall

Comment: still got a problem, when the target is behind a collider, playerInsight will be true, it should be false, because even if the target is behind collider the ray will casted and player insight will be true

Comment: @adhityawyratama Form what you've provided, I only know that you have to set `playerInSight = false;` where it's not relied on raycast result. Your code is neutralizing the condition.